# Does “Use <database>” clear/reset declared variables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Say I specified database to use,  declared a variable and put data into it like this

```
USE <database 1>;
GO

DECLARE @table TABLE(ID INT);
...
--inserted som stuff to @table
```

then specified a different database to use like this

```
USE <database 2>;
GO
```

would I still have the data inside the `@table` variable from the previous section under the second section? I'm quite new to SQL and I didn't know how to google to find an answer to this specific case.

Comment: Since you include `GO`, it will end table variable session.

Comment: Wouldn't this be rather simple for you to test yourself..?

Comment: @Larnu I realized  that and I did test it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you include `GO`, it will end table variable session.

If you are looking to use same table variable accross different database under same server, then you can call that database instead of `use <db name>`.

```
insert into db_name.schema.table_name( <column list> )
      select col1, col2, . . 
      from @table

insert into db_name.schema.table_name( <column list> )
      select col1, col2, . . 
      from @table
```

Comment: Thank you, I also did a bit of testing (which I should have probably done first) and found that just removing the `GO` clause does seem to work